# Implement "24 hour time" using an array of numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was recently given a question in an exam. 
I will be given an array of 4 numbers and using that I have to construct the largest possible 24 hour time format.
For eg : If the input array is [1,3,5,2] the answer would be "23:51".
 If the input array is [1,1,5,0] the answer would be "15:10".

I tried doing and did succeed but it was very rudimentary. I basically had to make 4 different arrays for each position of the time and compare with the input array.

A different approach with an implementation in any language(c, c#, objC or anything etc) would be of great help. I cant seem to get my head around my logic.

Comment: is 24:00 the largest or equal to 00:00 (that smallest)?

Comment: lets assume that the  largest would be 23:59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to share a working solution. Not necessarily efficient.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] input = {1,2,6,7};
        System.out.println(getLargestTime(input)+" is the largest time!");
    }

    public static String getLargestTime(int[] input) {
        String largestTime = "00:00";
        String str = input[0]+""+input[1]+""+input[2]+""+input[3];
        List<String> times = new ArrayList<>();
        permutation(str, times);
        Collections.sort(times, Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (String t: times) {
            int hours = Integer.parseInt(t) / 100;
            int minutes = Integer.parseInt(t) % 100;
            if (hours < 24 && minutes < 60) {
                if (hours < 10 && minutes < 10) {
                    largestTime = "0"+hours+":0"+minutes;
                } else if (hours < 10) {
                    largestTime = "0"+hours+":"+minutes;
                } else if (minutes < 10) {
                    largestTime = hours+":0"+minutes;
                } else {
                    largestTime = hours+":"+minutes;
                }               
            }
        }
        return largestTime;
    }

    public static void permutation(String str, List<String> list) { 
        permutation("", str, list); 
    }

    private static void permutation(String prefix, String str, List<String> list) {
        int n = str.length();
        if (n == 0) list.add(prefix);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n), list);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the largest number
2. Place that number in the front if it is legal (0, 1, or 2 in the first spot). If it isnt, find the biggest legal number and place it first.
3. Repeat 1-2 with second, third, etc. largest number until a legal number is found for front
4. Repeat 1-3 for second to front, second to last, and last
5. If you end up with illegal numbers at the end, then swap those illegal numbers with the earlier number that produces the latest time.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only 4 numbers, I would generate all possible time stamps (that would be `4!` i.e. `24`), sort them, and find the largest valid time stamp.

How to check if `t` is valid 24 hour time stamp?

- `t` is max 4 digits, i.e. `t mod 10000 == 0`
- the last two digits (`t mod 100`) is a valid minute value, i.e. in the range `[0-59]`
- the first two digits (`t div 100`) is a valid hour value, i.e. in the range `[0-23]`

Comment: Wont I have to use some system APIs to check if it is a valid timestamp?

Comment: @RajOlive It is something very simple that you need NOT to use API

Answer (score 0):

It's not the complete answer, just the complement part for @arun. 
For checking the valid time stamp, I assume the form of time stamp is ab:cd where a, b, c, d is the digits.

- a should be from 0 to 2
- If a smaller than 2, the b is all valid.
  Otherwise, b should be from 0 to 3
- c should be from 0 to 5
- d is all valid

You can use these constraints:

- To check valid time stamps after generated
  OR
- Use them to generate